# jquery scale scale function increases size exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale

I have a function that i'm using to scale pictures up on mouse-enter and return to normal size on mouse-out. The problem is if i quickly mouse-out and then mouse-in before the picture is allowed to return to normal size then the picture will scale up ( x2.7) from whatever size it currently is at on the moment of the mouse-enter ( and will no longer return to its original size)....so it gets huge!! how would I stop the function from running until the img has first returned to its original size? go to vgtesting.co.nf ( dog walking tab) to see what i'm trying to do.

```
//to scale up on hover
$('#videoandmapwrap').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: (current_w * 2.7),
            height: (current_h * 2.7)
        }, 900);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: current_w + 'px',
            height: current_h + 'px'
        }, 400);
    }
}, 'img');
```

Comment: I'm guessing one solution is to use conditional logic to have the function run only when the img is at its original size?

Comment: Have you try to define `current_h` and `current_w` globally and not inside the mouseenter function??

Comment: Have u tried this : make the size original variable static (meaning constant) .. and always multiple this value by 2.7 .. so that it remains to the allowed zoomed scale ?

Comment: If you define `current_h` and `current_w` globally all works: see example here: see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/Ku2fH/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ALAtj/5/ .. @Frogmouth - u should make this answer .. was trying the same on jsfiddle .. just beat me :)

Comment: thanks Frogmouth! it works better now!

Comment: :) lol... next time will your time :D

Comment: Little help, great pleasure. Enjpoy your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like my comment...

Your code seems valid. Only one thing is the two variables. They're not seems defined, and if the variables aren't defined they're limited on their scope (mouseenter function) and not in the other one mouseleave try to define the value globally.

```
var current_h,current_w; //add this line simply.
$('#videoandmapwrap').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
       //... your code
    }
}, 'img');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/Ku2fH

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that you have a race condition where the different eventhandlers are competing with each other.
One way to fix this would be to store the original size in the DOM when mouseenter is executed the first time and then always use this size when scaling instead of using the current size of the image.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this is a race condition. As long as the webbrowser stores the eventhandlers to be run in the order that the events occur, there will be no race condition. And storing the size in the DOM will have the same effect as using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag that allows to size. When mouse enter - put the flag to false and whe leaves - true. So size the picter up to the flag. Hope this helps.

```
var flag = true;
// inside mouseenter function
if(!flag) return;
flag = !flag;

// and then in mouseleave function
flag = !flag;
```

Hope this is enough to consider it answer.

Comment: This does not solve the race condition. It will still be two eventhandlers competing with each other to set/reset the flag.

Comment: Well, just thought was enough giving some isue, not the code, but will keep in mind ;-)

Comment: No, the flag must be changed BEFORE the animation. If the animation starts there is nothing to do, but doing it before must work.

Comment: simply defining the height & weight globally, as frogmouth suggested, fixed the problem. thank you all! however Mozilla stops responding after a few mouse-enters...